# Redirect when submit a taxonomy Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

On Drupal 7 I want to redirect to main listing on backend when I submit a term; by default if you submit a term you stay on the same add's page.

I have this code..

```
function MODULE_form_taxonomy_form_term_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
        if($form['#term']['vocabulary_machine_name'] == 'foo') {
            $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][]='form_foo_submit';
        }
}

function form_foo_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'admin/content/foo_view_list';
}
```

Well, I put these on Drupal 7 and works fine but the term not saves correctly!

Can anybody help me? Thx!

Comment: Another way would be to add **?destination=admin/content/foo_view_list** at the end of the term page URL. So it might be easier for you to change the link instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try drupal_goto instead of the redirect approach:

```
function form_foo_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  ...
  ...
  drupal_goto('admin/content/foo_view_list');'
}
```

Does that end up working?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your code to be something like:

```
function MODULE_form_taxonomy_form_term_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    if($form['#term']['vocabulary_machine_name'] == 'foo')
    {
        $form['#redirect'] = 'YOUR_NEW_PATH';
    }
}
```

Hope this helps... Muhammad.

Answer (score 0):

```
function MODULE_form_taxonomy_form_term_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
        if($form['#term']['vocabulary_machine_name'] == 'foo') {
            $form['#submit'][]='form_foo_submit';
        }
}
function form_foo_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'admin/content/foo_view_list';
}
```

this example works for me